# regular expression to remove background-color styles

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to go through the text in a div and replace "background-color:[whatever];" with "" wherever it occurs. Basically, I want to remove all the inline background-color styles.

It seems that JavaScript's

```
             string.replace(regex,str)
```

is  the right tool but the regex to first find "background-color:" and then replace that plus whatever follows up to and including the next";" with "" is not clear.

Could someone nudge me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Javascript is probably the right tool, regex not so much. There are actually ways to get the elements and manipulate the styles built into javascript, who would have thought ?

Comment: do you want to remove the styles from actual elements or from a 'code sample' conatained in a `<div>`

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is that when I call the browser's document.execCommand('justifyLeft', false, false) with a selecion it puts the selection in a span and adds an inline background-color to it. Then it puts the span in a div with text-align: left. The inline background-color style causes me a lot of grief so I want to follow the execCommand call with something that removes it.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of all `background-color`s or only if it is inline?

Comment: _“Could someone nudge me in the right direction?”_ – [there you go.](https://www.google.com/search?q=basic+regex+tutorial)

Comment: Regarding the "put on hold as unclear" request, why would you post  this two hours after the question has been understood and answered by experts? If you don't understand the question it's probably better to keep quiet than to mark down the question and request that it be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with the following script:

```
var all = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
    if (all[i].style.backgroundColor) {
        all[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
}
```

The reason I did this with a loop through the DOM and not with regex is for 2 reasons:

- If you use regex, you're going to have to make it work for every single background color, so you'd have to match `background-color:#fff;`, but also `background-color: /*either #fff; or #000;*/#fff;`, since comments can be placed there too. You'd require way too much regex to make it work perfectly, while this script does all that work for you.
- By modifying the HTML code instead of the DOM nodes, you'd also remove all event handlers attached to the elements. That means other scripts might not work anymore, since you've removed all event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I just whipped up a quick, pure-JS, no-regex solution in JSFiddle.  It goes through each child of an element (recursively) and, if it isn't a text node, sets the `background-color` to `transparent` (effectively removing it).

```
function removeChildBackgrounds(element) {
    var children = element.childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var node = children[i];
        if(node.nodeName !== '#text') {
            node.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
            if(node.hasChildNodes()) {
                removeChildBackgrounds(node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HqDnf/) here.

---

**Links:**

- [`.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes)
- [`.hasChildNodes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.hasChildNodes)
- [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joey and Sam.

It turned out that Joey's idea is all I needed. After converting to jQuery and taking advantage of the knowledge that cellContent$ is the outer div that execCommand last worked on and that it always puts the background-color in a `<span>` element, it became:

```
cellContent$.find('span')
            .each(function() {
              if(this.style.background) {
                this.style.background = '';
              }
             });
```

Thanks to both of you!

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you should do `$('span').css('background', '');`.  It will be much more familiar to the majority of people. [`$.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) can both read and set styles.